# regular expression (replacing v with version)

Tags: python, regex

**I would like to be able to replace the letter 'v' where necessary with 'Version'**

The current data is in the form of:

```
v6
version 6
v 6
```

**I have tried different variations of this to select only the necessary values to change to 'Version**

```
df.replace(to_replace = 'v[\d ]', value = 'version', regex = True)
```

**The expected output of the correct replace expression would be:**

```
version 6
version 6
version 6
```

Comment: I think you need a lookahead. Try `'v\s*(?=\d)'`

Comment: Try `v(?!ersion)`. How can you describe the requirements? What are the "only the necessary values"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?i)\bv\s*(\d+)
```

Replace each match with `version \1`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XAGzxB/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - to make the regex case-insensitive
- `\b` - a word-boundary
- `v\s*` - matches letter `v` followed by 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - matches and captures 1+ digits in group 1

Comment: Very well explained regex ++

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result = re.sub(r'v\s*(\d+)', 'version \\1', "v6\nversion 6\nv 6")
print(result)

output:
version 6
version 6
version 6
```

`v` match **v**

`\s*` match zero or more white space

`(\d+)` capturing group for one digits or more

Comment: This will match `anyv6` which probably isn't what OP wants